# Given a thread id, how to decide it's alive or not in C++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

Given only thread id, is it possible to decide from there whether the thread is still alive or not? I'm talking about C++ on linux.

Comment: @littleadv means "exists" and "not terminated".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manpage:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    The pthread_kill() function shall request that a signal  be  deliv-
>    ered to the specified thread.
>
>    As in kill(), if sig is zero, error checking shall be performed but
>    no signal shall actually be sent.
> ```

so:

```
bool isalive(int threadid)
{
  return pthread_kill(threadid, 0) != ESRCH;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. If pthread_kill works the same way as kill, it solves my problem.

Comment: By the way, any counterpart for this on Windows?

Comment: Not my area, I'm afraid ... a quick scan indicates `GetExitCodeThread` should indicate whether the target is still running.